# How to blunt sharp joints?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

In the following figure we can see that the line joints are so sharp. How to make them blunt?

```
\documentclass[10pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1.5,0)(10.5,7)
\psset{linecolor=blue,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none} 
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={110,135,135,135,-60}](2.22,2.24){O}(9,6){C}(4.82,3.68){A}(6,4.34){B}(5.45,1.58){D}(6.87,1.29){E}(8.87,0.88){F}
\pstLineAB[nodesepB=-1]{O}{C}
\pstLineAB[nodesepB=-1.5]{O}{F}
\foreach \a\b\c\d\e\g in {A/F/C/D/G/-90,B/F/C/D/H/90,A/F/C/E/I/-80,B/I/E/H/J/-30}{\pstInterLL[PosAngle=\g]{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}{\e}}
\psline(A)(F)(B)(I)
\psline(D)(C)(E)(H)
\pstLineAB[linestyle=dashed,nodesepA=-.5,nodesepB=-2]{O}{J}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\psset{linecolor=blue,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,linejoin=2} 
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell me know where is pst-news07.pdf? :-). I can't find it in http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/

Comment: Additional : I found linejoin in pst-news08.pdf page 7. :-). (very secret) ...

Comment: no, linejoin is present in the default documentation since 1990!

Comment: And the previous question, where is pst-news07.pdf? :-).

Comment: ?? There is no pst-news07.pdf

Comment: Please answer to me the reason pst-news07.pdf does not exist in that site. :-(

Comment: There was nothing new in that year